# How to get result ode2 as f(x)?

Tags: maxima

```
(%i1) 'diff(h,t) = - (r1^2/r2^2)*sqrt(2*g*h);
(%o1) 'diff(h,t,1)=-(sqrt(2)*sqrt(g*h)*r1^2)/r2^2

(%i2) ode2 (%o1,h,t);
(%o2) -(sqrt(2)*sqrt(g*h)*r2^2)/(g*r1^2)=t+%c
```

How to get result as function h(t)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_poly_solve`

```
load("to_poly_solve") $

eq: 'diff(h,t) = - (r1^2/r2^2)*sqrt(2*g*h) $
sol_diff: ode2 (eq,h,t) $

/* solve initial value problem */
sol_diff_ic: ic1(sol_diff, t=0, h=h0) $

assume(g>0, h0>0, r1>0, r2>0, t>0) $

/* get solution as a %union object, %ifs suggest that you have a
critical `t' where `h' becomes negative */
sol_union: to_poly_solve(sol_diff_ic, h);

/* "quick and dirty" extraction of one of the branches  */
hext(e):= block([opsubst: true, ans: []], subst(lambda([r, l], if r='h then ans: cons(l, ans)), "=", e), ans) $
sol_h: hext(sol_union)[1] $

/* plot solutions */
num1: subst([r1=1, r2=1, g=1/10, h0=1], sol_h) $
num2: subst([r1=1, r2=1, g=1,    h0=1], sol_h) $

plot2d([num1, num2], [t, 0, 1], [legend, false], [ylabel, "h"], [gnuplot_term, "dumb"]) $
                    1 +--------------------+
                      |++++   +    +   +   |
                  0.9 |++  ++++           +|
                  0.8 |+ +    ++++        +|
                      |   +      ++++      |
                  0.7 |+   ++       +++++ +|
                  0.6 |+    ++          +++|
                      |      ++            |
                  0.5 |+      ++          +|
                      |        +++         |
                  0.4 |+         ++       +|
                  0.3 |+          +++     +|
                      |             +++    |
                  0.2 |+              +++ +|
                  0.1 |+                +++|
                      |   +   +    +   +   |
                    0 +--------------------+
                      0  0.2 0.4  0.6 0.8  1
                                t
```